# Understanding the concept of universality

Tags: plato, universals

I have the requirement to understand what is meant by Platonist Universality. I am also interested in learning the difference (if there is any difference) between Aristotelian Universality and Platonist Universality. I am further grateful if someone could kindly explain the difference between Platonist Universality, Aristotelian Universality and Kantian Universality.

Comment: See [Universal (metaphysics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_(metaphysics)) and [Plato's theory of universals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_realism)

Comment: But the question is too broad... you are asking for a summary of the history of Western philosophy.

Comment: I agree with Mauro. You need to reduce the question to a more manageable focus.